# DDD and optimization for showing data in views

Tags: language-agnostic, domain-driven-design

This is a common requirement in many web-based projects: an entity has to show information to another related entity. For example, a book in an e-commerce site has to show relevant information about its author.

Let say I model both the book and author as an entity, how should I implement a feature which display a book and its author's information on the same page.

- I can make a call to the BookRepo to retrieve the book's information, and then another call to the AuthorRepo to retrieve the author, using the authorid inside the book entity. This is 2 queries
- I can write a query where I join the Book and Author tables together and retrieve both information in 1 query. But which repo does this query goes? Does this break DDD because I am assuming details about the Book and Author entity?

Which is the 'best practices', and what are other ways I can approach this problem?

(I am assuming using the use of standard SQL queries [such as PHP + MySQL], since in EF 4 you would define associations between Book and Author which would solve the problem rather easily).

Comment: Read up on [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Answer (score 1):

But even though you don't seems to use ORM's you probably have tto populate your entities from your SQL querys and your entities has to relate to each other in some way (collections, navigation properties etc...). 
If your domain contains entities that have no associations between each other, I wouldn't call it DDD since you lack some important ingredients like aggregates, value objects, bi-/unidirectional relationships.
But what do I know :-) Maybe you have made your puzzle well and this last piece is to merge entities into a "view" that can be useful for your clients.

Since repositories normally operates on an aggregate-root entity you can have repository methods like ListBooksByAuthor (BookRepository) or ListAuthors (AuthorRepository).

When you want to display complex data from many different aggregates in a web page I recommend using Data Transfer Objects. Let that DTO object be unique for that page or Use Case and being a "view" that displays all (or most of the) data that web page needs. 
I also recommend NOT using DTO's everywhere unless you're using web services. Using DTO's together gives both pros and cons. Together with a service layer it gives you a nive anti corruption layer and also gives you the place to inject Book and Author repository. Then from service layer you can assemble and reassemble DTO's (look at AutoMApper or similar...helps you a lot).
BUT to much DTO's everywhere also gives you overhead in maintenance of the application. It adds another layer to maintain. 
I prefer to just use it for certain clients/web pages.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this page](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2009/11/08/two-flavors-of-ddd/) it describes two ways to load and relate the aggregate roots. Linking this back to your example:

The Book class would encapsulate the relevant Author information as a Value Type so when the Book information is displayed on the web page it has all the information on the author it needs. If the users decides to view more information on the Author they can by following a link to an Author Page (whatever the requirement is).

If you have a service method called FindBookByTitle then
loading the Book entity would then load the relevant author information from the BookRepo.

```
class Author
{
  public Author(int authorID, FullName name) { }

  int AuthorID { get; }
  FullName Name { get; }
  List<BookDetails> AuthoredBooks { get; set; }
}

class BookDetails
{
  public BookDetails(int ID, string title) { }

  int BookID { get; }
  string Title { get; }
}

class Book
{
  public Book(int ID, string Title) { }

  int BookID { get; }
  string Title { get; }
  List<AuthorDetails> Writers { get; set; }
}

class AuthorDetails
{
  public AuthorDetails(int ID, FullName name) { }

  int AuthorID { get; }
  public FullName fullName { get; }
}

class FullName
{
  public FullName(string name, string surname) { }

  public string Name { get; }
  public string Surname { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet solution to this, but you have a few options.

Your first proposed solution of making a call to two repositories is perfectly valid and happens all the time in practice. For example, it takes over a hundred different services to render an Amazon product page. Each service is responsible for providing data specific to its bounded context. You can create a service called something like BookService which calls the two repositories to return a reporting object or a DTO that has all the data that you need for the particular view. If you feel that performance is due to two repository calls is going to be an issue, you can employ caching, or CQRS to create appropriate read models, but don't jump  to those solutions prematurely.

**But which repo does this query goes?** 
I would just add it to the BookRepository, or even a whole new repository called BookDetailsReportingRepository, perhaps a method called GetBookDetails.  This method would not return an editable entity, but a reporting object which is a projection of values from multiple entities.

**Does this break DDD because I am assuming details about the Book and Author entity?**
This does not violate DDD and in my opinion makes it easier to apply. Just regard as the data returned by the aforementioned repository as reporting objects, not entities.